# How to parse arbitrary RDF IRI through javascript?

Tags: javascript, sparql, rdf, linked-data, iri

RDF IRI such as:

- https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns
- https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/dublin_core_terms.ttl
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GENEPIO_0100155
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCBITaxon_2697049
- ......

I know that RDF IRI returns RDF data.

I want to parse arbitrary RDF IRI and show it as a list on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been resolved.

I use [rdflib.js](https://github.com/linkeddata/rdflib.js) to parse `HTTP RDF IRI`:

- https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Resource_Description_Framework
- ... (if server allow CORS)

But `javascript` can't parse CORS requests:

- https://www.dublincore.org/specifications/dublin-core/dcmi-terms/dublin_core_terms.ttl
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/GENEPIO_0100155
- http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCBITaxon_2697049
- ... (if server doesn't allow CORS)

Answer (score 1):

IRI (Internationalized Resource Identifier) is an extension of the URI. It does not *return* data, it is an *identifier*. There is also no "RDF" IRI/URI; all the URIs you list are "http" or "https" URIs. Parsing such a URI would mean splitting it into parts like "http", "www.w3.org", and "/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns".

Usually the web server is configured to produce semantic data (in Turtle, RDF/XML, JSON-LD, RDFa etc.; you'd use content negotiation to get one of the formats you understand) when you navigate to URIs actually denoting a vocabulary, but it doesn't have to.

There are [libraries for JS for working with RDF](https://rdf.js.org/), but if you want to do this in a web page, with client-side JavaScript, you are out of luck ‒ JavaScript doesn't allow you to retrieve the content of a cross-domain page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!


That's what I want to do:
```text
Develop an RDF Brower(an HTML Project), use javascript to parse the "https" URIs of any address (as above), and show it in the form of list, RDF graph, etc. 
```


I use `Apache Jena` to parse RDF in java projects, and I will try [rdfjs](https://github.com/rdfjs/N3.js) in this html projects.


Best regards

Comment: @chenkun So you are interested in something like [this](https://uri4uri.is4.site/uri.html/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440583/how-to-parse-arbitrary-rdf-iri-through-javascript/74444227), i.e. to parse a URI and represent it in RDF?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking forward to making an html project that everyone can embed directly into any web project.